# Wordpress TinyMCE & wisywyg strips & changes span

Tags: wordpress

Ok i want to implement a responsive image into my Wordpress pages. For that i found an article that learned me to work with Picturefill.

this is my code into the TINYMCE editor:

```
<span data-picture data-alt="My responsive image">
    <span data-src="http://localhost:88/mywpwebsite/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/picture_200.png"></span>
   <span data-src="http://localhost:88/mywpwebsite/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/picture_300" data-media="(min-width: 768px)"></span>
   <span data-src="http://localhost:88/mywpwebsite/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/picture_400.png" data-media="(min-width: 1200px)"></span>
    <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
    <noscript>
        <img src="picture_200.png" alt="My responsive image">
    </noscript>
</span>
```

when i change from the TINYMCE editor to wisywyg editor than it strips my code to this:

```
<span data-picture="" data-alt="My responsive image"><span data-picture="" data-alt="My responsive image">



<!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. --><noscript>
        <img src="picture_200.png" alt="My responsive image">
</noscript></span></span>&nbsp;
```

when i stay on the TINYMCE and save the page it works but i have some spaces into my browser. If i look at the source code i see this:

```
<span data-picture data-alt="My responsive image"><br />
    <span data-src="http://localhost:88/Controle_direct_WP/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/energieprestatiecertificaat_200.png"></span><br />
   <span data-src="http://localhost:88/Controle_direct_WP/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/energieprestatiecertificaat_300.png" data-media="(min-width: 768px)"></span><br />
   <span data-src="http://localhost:88/Controle_direct_WP/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/energieprestatiecertificaat_400.png" data-media="(min-width: 1200px)"></span><br />
</span><br />
    <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. --></p>
<noscript>
        <img src="picture_200.png" alt="My responsive image"><br />
    </noscript>
```

i think the problem showing up because of the span tags. But i cannot seem to find a good solution. I cannot disable the wisywyg editor because my client has to change the content itself in the future